# Split integers in a list (python)

Tags: python, list, integer

In python how would I make a list such as `[18, 8]` into something like `[1, 8, 8]`?

I've already tried doing

```
list1 = [18, 8] 
list2 = [list1[i : i + 1] for i in range(0, len(times_two_even_even_indexes))]
```

but that just gives me

```
list2 = [18], [8]]
```

Answer (score 1):

For the following solution I would add the disclaimer: "don't do it at home"...

```
lst = [18, 8]
map(int, sum(map(lambda x: list(str(x)), lst), [])) #[1, 8, 8]
```

**Explanation**:
`str(x)` transforms each integer into a string, then uses the `list` builtin function in order to separate the string into list of characters (each of which is a single digit).

The `sum(..., [])` flattens the list and the last `map(int, ...)` transforms back every "string-digit" into an integer.

Answer (score 1):

You can join all the ints into a single string then map each digit/char in the string to an int:

```
list1 = [18, 8]

print(list(map(int,"".join(map(str, list1)))))
[1, 8, 8]
```

Or use a list comp calling str on each int and iterating over each char:

```
 list1 = [18, 8]

print([int(ch) for i in list1 for ch in str(i)])
[1, 8, 8]
```

Comment: Nice! In the first solution the wrapping `list` is redundant.

Comment: @alfasin, if using python3 you will need to call list on the map

Comment: @alfasin,I usually always stick a `list(map..` unless the question is tagged specifically for python2

Comment: I totally agree: defensive programming :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the most dense form I've tried
Inner loop converts list to string then with itertools.chain flatten the strings to characters and finally convert it back to integers

```
import itertools
list2 = [int(y) for y in list(itertools.chain(*[str(x) for x in list1]))]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
intlist = [18, 8]
digitlist = [int(digit) for number in intlist for digit in str(number)]
print digitlist
```

This converts each number in the list to a string, then converts each character in the string back into an int. By using a double-for (`for a in b for x in y`) in a list comprehension, only one list item is output for each character inside the `intlist`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#since string is iterable convert to string,
#chain it, and convert back to int

from itertools import  chain

print(list(map(int,chain.from_iterable(map(str,[18, 8])))))

[1, 8, 8]
```